# How to get distance to different POI around lat/lon?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have about 150k lat/lon points with osmid located around Worldwide. These points was exported from planet.osm and I need to get a distance to different nearest POIs(cities, seas, infrastructure objects and etc) for each lat/lon. I`v make script that make a Overpass QL requests to overpass-turbo.eu (openstreetmap api) but It seems that will take about 250 hours to get all information and not suitable :) Can somebody suggest a better way?

Comment: Perhaps download the POI data to something local (e.g spatialite). It would help if you can provide more detail on exactly what you're doing and the area of your sample points. At least show the query.  If you are really planning to do 150k queries in less than 10 days, you're probably abusing the service: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API#Introduction says 10k / day is reasonable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I need get distance to nearest city, infrastructure objects, seas/oceans/lakes and etc. here is the overpass ql:

    [out:json]; 
    node(1325598475); 
    node 
    (around:30000) 
    ["place"~"village|town|city"]; 
    out skel qt 100;

By the way I have openstreetmaps nodes ID.

Comment: Please edit the question with the important details - just click edit below the question. What area are the sample points in? How big is that area?

Comment: My points located around the worldwide

Comment: Please edit the question with the important details - just click edit below the question. No more warnings.

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/45350/how-to-make-overpass-ql-query-from-local-osmpbf

Answer (score 1):

Just found a few another solutions maybe it will help somebody:

1. Wolfram Cloud have a nice web editor where you can upload your data
   and make some coputations including with geo data.They have some
   usefull methods such as GeoNearest
   https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoNearest.html There is
   a free acess with some limitations. By the way to find information
   using Wolfram for list with 150k points It seems will cost me a lot
2. Another usefull free tool is QGIS http://www.qgis.org/ru/site/ it
   have Distance matrix. I will extract data from planet.osm with
   "tags" for example city/towns and etc and then calculate distance in
   QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

overpass-api may be used to extract data, but such processing as described here should (must?) be done outside it.

QGIS or a custom script are initial ideas.